# Firestore write batch in WPF using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using [google-cloud-dotnet](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/index.html) library to work with **Firestore** in my **WPF** program using **c#**

I need to write large amount of documents at once, about 2000 documents.. So I have to find a way better than writing a single document each time

Found [WriteBatch](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/api/Google.Cloud.Firestore.WriteBatch.html) class, and tried the following :

```
var batch = new WriteBatch();

DocumentReference docRef = db.Document("cities/myCity");
batch = batch.Set(docRef, new {
    Name = "Los Angeles",
    Country = "USA",
    State = "CA",
});

batch.CommitAsync();
```

but **couldn't initiate** the batch correctly, getting an error :

> **WriteBatch** does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

So could you please explain how should I initiate the **batch writing** to be used later ?

Answer (score 2):

After some researching I was able to use `batch` write successfully, **example** :

```
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;

// ...

System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "myCredentials.json");
FirestoreDb db = await FirestoreDb.CreateAsync("myProject");

var batch = db.StartBatch();

DocumentReference docRef = db.Document("cities/myCity");
batch = batch.Set(docRef, new {
    Name = "Los Angeles",
    Country = "USA",
    State = "CA",
});

batch.CommitAsync();
```